# How to save checkbox value into Access?

Tags: vb.net

i have vb.net Applicationt contains Year months as Checkbox. I have following code to these items, the checkbox items is saved months into Access correctly, but when i return to the interface the checkbox aren't showing who's checked . So what to do?

'''
Dim janvier As String
Dim fevrier As String
Dim mars As String
Dim avril As String
Dim mai As String
Dim jui As String
Dim juil As String
Dim aout As String
Dim sept As String
Dim octo As String
Dim nov As String
Dim decem As String

```
    If ch_jan.Checked Then

        janvier = ch_jan.Text
        janvier = "valide"
    Else
        janvier = "<------>"
    End If


    If ch_fev.Checked Then
        fevrier = ch_fev.Text
        fevrier = "valide"
    Else
        fevrier = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_mar.Checked Then
        mars = ch_mar.Text
        mars = "valide"
    Else
        mars = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_apr.Checked Then
        avril = ch_apr.Text
        avril = "valide"
    Else
        avril = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_mai.Checked Then
        mai = ch_apr.Text
        mai = "valide"
    Else
        mai = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_jui.Checked Then
        jui = ch_jui.Text
        jui = "valide"
    Else
        jui = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_juil.Checked Then
        juil = ch_juil.Text
        juil = "valide"
    Else
        juil = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_aou.Checked Then
        aout = ch_aou.Text
        aout = "valide"
    Else
        aout = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_sept.Checked Then
        sept = ch_sept.Text
        sept = "valide"
    Else
        sept = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_oct.Checked Then
        octo = ch_oct.Text
        octo = "valide"
    Else
        octo = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_nov.Checked Then
        nov = ch_nov.Text
        nov = "valide"
    Else
        nov = "<------>"
    End If

    If ch_dec.Checked Then
        decem = ch_dec.Text
        decem = "valide"
    Else
        decem = "<------>"
    End If


    Dim dtadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_Adherent, MaConnection)
    savinto.Connection = MaConnection
    savinto.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    savinto.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Adherent(code_adh, nom, prenom, sexe, date_entrer, Photo,duree,rest,jan,fev,mar,avr,mai,jui,juil,out,sep,oct,nov,decem)" & " Values ('" & (txt_code_adh.Text) & "','" & txt_nom_adh.Text & "','" & txt_prenom_adh.Text & "','" & cmb_sexe.Text & "', '" & txt_date_entrer.Text & "','" & txt_lien_photo.Text & "','" & cmb_duree.Text & "','" & txt_rest.Text & "','" & janvier & "','" & fevrier & "','" & mars & "','" & avril & "','" & mai & "','" & jui & "','" & juil & "','" & aout & "','" & sept & "','" & octo & "','" & nov & "','" & decem & "')"
    MaConnection.Open()
    savinto.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dtset.Clear()
    dtadapter.Fill(dtset, "Adherent")
    MaConnection.Close()
    MsgBox(" Votre nouveau Adherent est bien Enregistrer")

End Sub
```

'''

Comment: First or foremost, use parameters to avoid sql injection or formatting errors.

Comment: Your values should be the checkbox.checked value, not the textbox.text. To do it properly, use parameters instead, which you can set directly.

Comment: You should be using the data type that represents Boolean data in your database. For Access that would be `Yes/No`. In your VB code, you then save `True` or `False` to those columns and you get that Boolean value from the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox`. Doing things properly, your SQL might be like `INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES (@MyColumn)` and then you'd add the parameter like `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyColumn", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = myCheckBox.Checked`.

Comment: What is the point of assigning `janvier = ch_jan.Text` and then on the very next line assigning a different value `janvier = "valide"` which simply overwrites the first the first line? You do this for every checkbox.